# Link to the App page on AmazonStore in developing app

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

Can I get link to my app on AmazonStore if the app not published yet?

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=apps.tarun.ecardsender (Replace the package name with your own)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the app package name then you will be able to link to it using:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=[PACKAGE_NAME]
```

E.g. [VG Inventory Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=com.numan1617.vginventory)

Full linking details can be found [here](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/community/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android.html).

That being said, if your app has yet to be published then you will likely get a 404 as it will need to go through the review process.

Comment: Thanks. And what string parameter I need to open directly the rate page of the app?